# Using control from resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I try using MVVM for my application since it makes stuff easier. So my menu item is a data-class bound to a button with a custom style (the style actually binds the underlying data).

The thing is that these menu items can optionally have additional content which can be set to `Collapsed` if not needed. This works quite fine so far, but switching to MVVM brings up some problems. I need to define the additional content somewhere and attatch it programmatically to the menu items.

Design work in code is a bad approach. So I thought of using WPFs resource system. I tried inserting the content into the resources which works. I can specify the control as is there.

But when I try to load it via the `FindResource()`-method, it doesn't find anything. I put it into various places and called the code at different states (Window constructor, Loaded-event, ...) but nowhere can it find this control.

I tried it with `Application.Current.Resources[...]`, `Application.Current.FindResource(...)` as well as the same with the Window class. It always comes up a `ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException`.

Moreover when put in resource files it gives me an parsing exception that says I can't use `x:Name` on resource objects. So I basically can't use the whole system since I need names in order to bind stuff between child elements of that control.

Is this even possible? Is it intended to be used that way? Is there a better approach of achieving this? That's again the point where I don't get the design principles of WPF ...

PS: I tried using *Page* and *Resource* as compile options for the .xaml-file.

That's the control:

```
<views:AnimatedStackPanel x:Key="LiftMenuAnalyzeContent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical" >
<views:AnimatedStackPanel.Children>
    <StackPanel x:Name="PaneAnalysisStep" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <shared:Triangle Width="20" Height="24" ApexSide="Left"
                                            Fill="#ff8000" />
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#ff8000"
                                BorderBrush="#ff8000" BorderThickness="0" Padding="4">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TxtAnalysisStep" Text="Analyzing" />
        </Border>
        <shared:Triangle Width="20" Height="24" ApexSide="Right"
                                            Fill="#ff8000" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="GridAnalysisInfo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label x:Name="LblObjectsFound" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                                Content="0" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Content="Targets" />
        <Label x:Name="LblIssuesFound" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                                Content="0" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Content="Issues" />
        <Label x:Name="LblErrorsFound" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"
                                Content="0" />
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Content="Errors" />
    </Grid>

    <TextBlock Margin="0,5,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"
                                Text="Not possible." TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</views:AnimatedStackPanel.Children>
```

Comment: No, this is not the correct way to go about it. The fact you're trying to use `FindResource` and `Application.Current.Resources` indicates you're still using code-behind, which isn't MVVM. It's virtually impossible to answer this question because the code you posted doesn't appear to match your description. You talk about a menu with custom content yet the XAML you've provided is a StackPanel with labels on a Grid. What is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: The problem is not the menu. The menu works fine, the style as well. If I add an instance of this menu item (only properties with INotifyChangedProperty) it does display the item correctly. But isn't MVVM about having a collection of items you bind to and then it automatically creates the view from the model (the menu item is the model in this case). So I create these menu items in code, because it should be dynamic. The content I want to add to this one though should be declared somewhere, cause creating this control is a lot of work if done in code. So I have to load it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a dynamic menu in MVVM then you need to start by declaring a view model for each menu item containing a header, a field for your dynamic content (more on this in a moment) and a list of any child menu items:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Header {get; set;}
    public object Content {get; set;}
    public MenuItemViewModel[] Children { get; set; }
}
```

Then your view model needs to create a tree of these structures:

```
public class DemoViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MenuItemViewModel[] MenuItems {get; set;}

    public DemoViewModel()
    {
        this.MenuItems = new MenuItemViewModel[]
        {
            new MenuItemViewModel{
                Header = "File", Content="icon.png",
                Children = new MenuItemViewModel[]
                {
                    new MenuItemViewModel{Header="Open", Content="icon.png"},
                    new MenuItemViewModel{Header="Save", Content="icon.png"},
                    new MenuItemViewModel{Header="Close", Content="icon.png"},
                }
            },
            new MenuItemViewModel{
                Header = "Edit", Content="icon.png",
                Children = new MenuItemViewModel[]
                {
                    new MenuItemViewModel{Header="Cut", Content="icon.png"},
                    new MenuItemViewModel{Header="Copy", Content="icon.png"},
                    new MenuItemViewModel{Header="Paste", Content="icon.png"},
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Displaying this menu is simply a matter of binding your Menu to the MenuItems and specifying a HeirarchicalDataTemplate so that it knows how to draw them:

```
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Menu.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.Resources>
    </Menu>
```

Result:

[image]

In this example I've explicitly made the ContentPresenter display what's in the `Header` property, but you can override that to anything you want. In my original view model I've added a `Content` property and set them all to `icon.png` which I'll assume is a resource, I can display it by using an Image with a BitmapImage source:

```
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Content}" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Result:

[image]

In this particular example I've hard-coded it to be an Image and to assume that `Content` will always be a string, but with DataTemplating you can make `Content` any class you want and also specify how each one should be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I think I've got that right so far then. After all it does work that way. My particular issue here is that I don't have an Icon as content  but a whole hierarchy of a control. The one I've posted in the original post - that is one kind of content. But declaring this one in code is one hell of work and super unflexible. I would like to declare it like any view in XAML, load it in the "DemoViewModel", add bindings to particular elements of that "hierarchy of controls" and then set it as content of one menu item. But as mentioned: I can't load it from resources.

Comment: That's fine, just put everything in a DataTemplate and represent it in your view model with a custom class. Alternatively put it in a ControlTemplate and set it as the MenuItem's template using a DataTrigger. Either way, you never have to create view controls or access resources directly in the code-behind or view models.